# Serial port unavaliable arduino

Tags: linux, arduino, serial-port, linux-mint

Trying to upload a code to arduino, but whether in the Arduino IDE or Arduino Create, both return this erro while uploading. Running on Linux Tara(mint 19 cinnamon).

```
./opt/arduino-builder/arduino-builder -compile -core-api-version 10611 -hardware opt/arduino-builder/hardware -hardware ./opt/cores -tools opt/arduino-builder/tools -tools ./opt/tools -built-in-libraries opt/libraries/latest -logger humantags -fqbn arduino:avr:mega:cpu=atmega2560 -build-cache /tmp -build-path /tmp/716441957/build -verbose -libraries /tmp/716441957/custom -libraries /tmp/716441957/pinned /tmp/716441957/sketch_oct8a

Sketch uses 8280 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 253952 bytes.

Global variables use 443 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 7749 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 8192 bytes.

Programming with: Serial

Flashing with command:/home/jesus/.arduino-create/arduino/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/bin/avrdude -C/home/jesus/.arduino-create/arduino/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino9/etc/avrdude.conf -q -q -patmega2560 -cwiring -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino-create-agent734074237/sketch_oct8a.hex:i

avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied

ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to solve this issue. In addition to it, you are not using an IDE. I will list the things you need to check, I am sure this will solve your problem.

I am not good at Linux environment so I will refer to applications names as window, you go the corresponding application in Linux.

1. Go to linux device manager and see for your arduino board. It should have proper naming like "arduino uno at port 3", then use the correct port in your command. If this name does not come properly then it means Driver is not available in your machine. So, go to step2.
2. Find the driver online and install it in your system, I am not sure about the support of linux with arduino, once it is done please repeat step1.

So, I conclude in short that you do not have the proper driver (which is strongly believe) or pointing the wrong port. I am not an expert with the `udev` rules, but it is definitely an issue you can experience with these kinds of micro-controllers.

Answer (score 0):

1#
First, check the port in your IDE. In Arduino tools->port
If the port is hidden or you can not move the cursor over this then run this commands in your terminal.If everything ok then skips this and follow the second part.

```
sudo apt-get install librxtx-java -y

sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER 

sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

2#
After this again check the first method. If it is not working then run this commands

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another program running which is already using this port.
You should close most other programs like putty or another serial monitor app.
Otherwise, try to reconnect the Arduino to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I know that these ideas below come from using a Teensy, but they may help you.

1. Sometimes there are the `ACM*` ports listed in the Arduino IDE. Try looking at the `ser` ports. I know when I am running my Teensy, sometimes I have them switched and need to select the correct one.
2. Also, from my experience with the Teensy, you might need to add a `udev` rule to allow permissions to access the port from non-root user. Here is the [link](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_download.html) that shows the [udev](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules) file.